# WPF Binding with RelativeSource Self

Tags: wpf, binding, self

I am confused with whn to use {RelativeSource Self} when binding. The below three bindings look the same to me, where MyText is a property in my view model.

```
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path=MyText RelativeSource{RelativeSource Self} }" />
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding MyText RelativeSource{RelativeSource Self} }" />
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding MyText }" />
```

When should I use Self in my binding? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two are equivalent, and bind to the `MyText` property of the `TextBlock` itself. But of course, they don't work, because there is no `MyText` property on `TextBlock`.

The third binds to the `MyText` property of the current `DataContext`

Use `RelativeSource.Self` when you need to bind to a property of the current control.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And the DataContext of TextBlock should be the same as its parent's if not specified?

Comment: @Helic, yes. The value of the DataContext is inherited by child elements, unless explicitly replaced.

Comment: also if I define a control template to replace the default display template for a control, what is the data context for textblock?<dxe:ComboBoxEdit.DisplayTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowData.Row.Cities3, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}"></TextBlock>
        </ControlTemplate>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit.DisplayTemplate>

Comment: @Helic, it depends on where the control is instantiated. The control template doesn't change anything about that. But anyway, in most cases a control template shouldn't try to use the DataContext. That's what DataTemplates are here for.